# jQuery flot: graphTable plugin how to show months

Tags: jquery, graph, flot

I am busy with my statics and now I want to show some months instead of numbers. But when I put some names of months in the table the statics are going crazy.

When you use numbers everything works ok, but I want to use numbers and months in the x-axis.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fed up with the way FLOT handles timestamps. The automatick tick generator messes about too much (see my last comment above). Much better to do your own thing. Convert the month names to an offset in a "months" array, then use:

`xaxis: {tickSize: 1; tickFormatter: function(v, a) {return months[v]}}`

to get the x-axis you want.

```
$("table.statics-date").each(function() {
    var colors = [];
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    $("table.statics-date thead th:not(:first)").each(function() {
        colors.push($(this).css("color"));
    });
    $(this).graphTable({
        series: 'columns',
        position: 'replace',
        height: '200px',
        colors: colors,
        xaxisTransform: function(month) {
            var i=0; 
            while ((i < 12) && (month != months[i])){i++}
            return i;
        }
    }, {
        xaxis: {
            tickSize: 1,
            tickFormatter: function(v, a) {return months[v]}
       }
    });
});
```

You'll have to mess about a bit when you gover a year end (Dec -> Jan), but the code isn't too difficult.

See my JSFIDDLE of this at: http://jsfiddle.net/G4TJ3/6/
Regards Neil

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You need to include an "xaxisTransform" option to the graphTable options and add a second parameter which is an "xaxis" option to "flot" itself. Basically you have to convert the month names to a timestamp to be plotted, then convert the timestamp back to a month for the x-axis.

Tour call to graphTable should be something like:

```
$(this).graphTable({
    series:        'columns',
    position:      'replace',
    height:        '200px',
    colors:         colors,
    xaxisTransform: function(month){return Date.parse(month + ' 1, 1970');}
   }
   ,
   {
    xaxis: {
            mode:       'time',
            timeformat: '%b'
           }
   } 
);
```

I already checked this in your JSFIDDLE and it works.

You don't have to use timestamps. You could supply your own functions, e.g. the xaxisTransform could just convert the month name to an offset [0-11], while for the flot option you would use instead:

```
    xaxis: {
            transform: function(monthOffset){return ..monthname as a string..;}
           }
```

ACTUALLY THAT LAST BIT IS WRONG, I THINK IT SHOULD BE 'transform' AND 'inverseTransform'.
Regards
       Neil

Comment: Hi Neil, thnx this is working! But when you have the 12 months (Jan - Dec) you will not see Dec in the xasis? Why is that? http://jsfiddle.net/G4TJ3/ ... and in IE this is not working?

Comment: Hi, regarding IE, From the https://github.com/flot/flot webpage: Generally, all browsers that support the HTML5 canvas tag are
supported.

For support for Internet Explorer < 9, you can use Excanvas, a canvas
emulator; this is used in the examples bundled with Flot. You just
include the excanvas script like this:

  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

Comment: Regarding December" not appearing, it's to do with the automatic generation of ticks on the x-axis. A fudge is to change the code to say:         xaxisTransform: function(month) {
            return (month == 'Jan') ? Date.parse(month + ' 1, 1970')
                                    : Date.parse(month + ' 2, 1970');
        }  You might also want to add the "xaxis" option "ticks: 12".

Comment: Hi Neil, i was talking about IE 9.0 i know that excanvas is needed for older versions. Here is a screenshot: http://i51.tinypic.com/2itr5f5.jpg ... And when i add the ticks option with the new xaxis code i get some errors.

Comment: Hi, your screenshot shot shows that the HTML has <th>1</th>... rather than <th>Jan</th>. You must have edited the HTML in the JSFIDDLE to numbers rather than names and forgot to put it back. I had the same problem when I used your JSFIDDLE yesterday. As to the "ticks" error, it worked fine for me. Are you sure you didn't miss out a comma ","? As in: xaxis: (ticks: 12, mode: 'time', timeformat: '%b'}

Comment: Hi Neil, one question, when i now use only 4 months instead of 12 some months duplicate them self. See: http://jsfiddle.net/G4TJ3/ for example.

Comment: Hi, again it's the plot package trying to create a nice x-axis for you. Just overide the default by using "ticks: 4" (see http://jsfiddle.net/elusien/G4TJ3/3/). without this FLOT is trying to create an x-axis with numbers from 0 (Jan) to 91*24*60*60*1000 (milliseconds to 2nd Apr - timestamp) and putting tick marks where it deems appropriate. Then it converts these timestamps to dates and extracts the month (%b). That is why you see two 'Jans', one of which is the 1st of Jan and the second of which is the 15th. Force to only put tick marks where you want by "ticks: 4," Regards

Comment: Hi, One last point - have you considered using HIGHCHARTS ( http://www.highcharts.com/ ) for your plotting, instead of FLOT? It looks good and I'm going to try it for some of my charts in the near future. Regards

Comment: Hmm ok... i don't want to use the tick option because sometimes i will have 3 months and maybe 10 days later i wil have 10 months.

Comment: And the HighCharts looks nice... but it's not free :-(

Comment: Hi, concerning the number of months to plot, you can make it automatic by using the option: "ticks: $("table.statics-date tr").length -1,".    HIGHCHARTS is free for non-commercial use, $80 for a single website license and $350 for a single developer license. Luckily my website ( http://www.trips.elusien.co.uk ) is non-commercial, but, if you are a commercial concern, then $350 doesn't seem exhorbitant.

Comment: Hi Neil, awsome :)... i find out that: ticks: $("table.statics-date tr").length -2 did the job instead of -1! But now i must alwasy begin with Jan... when i have only Aug to Dec in the statics then Aug is not visible in the xasis. So is it possible to make the return (month == 'Jan') ? Date.parse(month + ' 1') : Date.parse(month + '2'); variable to?

Comment: Hi, I've changed tack, since messing about with timestamps and x-axis ticks is a nightmare. FLOTs automatic tick generator gets in the way too many times. See me new answer below. Regards

Answer (score 1):

I am using `timeformat:"%d %b %y"` as stated in [flot official docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data)

```
%a: weekday name (customizable)
%b: month name (customizable)
%d: day of month, zero-padded (01-31)
%e: day of month, space-padded ( 1-31)
%H: hours, 24-hour time, zero-padded (00-23)
%I: hours, 12-hour time, zero-padded (01-12)
%m: month, zero-padded (01-12)
%M: minutes, zero-padded (00-59)
%q: quarter (1-4)
%S: seconds, zero-padded (00-59)
%y: year (two digits)
%Y: year (four digits)
%p: am/pm
%P: AM/PM (uppercase version of %p)
%w: weekday as number (0-6, 0 being Sunday)
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/UEePE/3106/)